# Change textcolors of Android ListView text on selection

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong...

I have a ListView with a custom layout.xml file. In there, i define a TextView like this

```
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:text="foo"
          android:textColor="@drawable/listitem_textcolor_selector"/>
```

The listitem_textcolor_selector.xml looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

This kind of works. If I select a row, it will properly change the color of the text to red. The only problem is, that it will not stay red. ***After a second or so, that color will change back to black.***

The main problem here is that the background of the row will change it's color and this color will stay, but the color of the text does not, even though the selector for the list item itself looks identical (expect the colors).

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?
Any help is appreciated as I have no idea on how to fix this :)

Thanks

**Edit:**
Maybe I should also point out that I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 tablet. I once heard something about "TouchMode" without really knowing weather this will have something to do with my problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the listitem_textcolor_selector.xml add these states:

```
        <!-- Activated -->      
<item 
    android:state_activated="true" 
    android:color="#ff0000" />

        <!-- Active -->      
<item 
    android:state_active="true" 
    android:color="#ff0000" />
```

After this, the selected item will keep it's color state until something else is selected.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you Lonut, after an hour of desperation found your solution

Answer (score 4):

I win the problem!
In selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
    <item  android:state_activated="true"  android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_active="true" android:color="#ff0000" />  
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:color="#000000" />
</selector>
```

In activity: myListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                     pl=position;
                     myListView.setItemChecked(pl, true);
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                          .....
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    />
```

And my checked item in red color after i click them. Only one checked item. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I got the trick. if you are using a custom xml for your list item,then you can change text color like:

**custom_listitem:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>     
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="7dip"
        android:paddingBottom="7dip"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@drawable/listitem_textcolor_selector"
         />
```

And now you will have to use this xml name to your array adapter which you use to populate your listview.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_listitem, options);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: My main problem is, that there is not just one TextView...


My custom_list_item.xml as more that one TextView in there and all of them have different colors in "not selected" state, but should all have the same color in "selected" state.


Anyway, i pass the R.layout.list_entry.xml file to my custom subclass of ArrayAdapter...

Comment: then you need to have different textcolor_selector file and set them accordingly to all your textview or wherever you require to change color.

Comment: So basically,in different text_selector files,you just need to change color for normal state..no other option i can see for meeting your requirement.

Comment: I do have several color selector files... something like this:

    <LinearLayout>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textColor="@color/textView1_color_selector"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:textColor="@color/textView2_color_selector"/>
    </LinearLayout>


Is this what you mean? Because that way it's not working :(

Comment: no...not like that.what i say is- as you prepared listitem_textcolor_selector,prepare other files with same code but change color for normal state in each of them accroding to the normal textcolors you want for different component in your xml.

Comment: And then you need to use them like android:textColor="@drawable/listitem_textcolor_selector1",android:textColor="@drawable/listitem_textcolor_selector2" etc. for various components according to its normal state color.

Comment: And yes,you should be able to use Color.xml's color in your selector file.

Comment: But if i understood you right, this is exactly what I have.
I'll try to explain my list_entry.xml file first. In there i have a LinearLayout with several TextViews... For _each_ of them i do have a separate "android:textColor" selector. Each of those selectors is a different one.

The funny thing is that it works for a second or so after the click, but then it turns back into its "normal" state. And I don't know why, as the background of the whole row stays in selected state. It's just the text that is changing back.

As i mentioned in my edit, I am trying this on a Samsung Galaxy Tab...

Comment: OK...sorry,i might get your problem wrongly.bt anyways,the solution i have given you works fine here!

Comment: Even if you may seem I am dump ;) Can you show me some sample code of how this could work? :)
I would really appreciate it! Thanks

Comment: sorry..i dnt hv any code that can solve your issue you explained to me in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

save `listitem_textcolor_selector.xml` in the `color folder of your res` and then use it like this: `android:textColor="@color/listitem_textcolor_selector"`

Comment: Thanks for the hint to save it in a more appropriate folder :)

But unfortunately this did not do the trick... :(