# Change highlighted text color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, textview

How can I change text color of highlighted text when User selects text for copy paste.

[image]
In this image I want to change the color of text

> world

from black to white. how can I do that?

I tried adding ColorStateList as drawable but it didn't help.
My TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/light_blue"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure it is possible without doing it yourself :

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    ... Constructors, ...

    private ForegroundColorSpan mSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(0xffff0000);

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        // make sure the text is spannable
        if (type == BufferType.NORMAL) {
            type = BufferType.SPANNABLE;
        }
        super.setText(text, type);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

        Spannable txt = (Spannable) getText();

        // ok even if not currently attached
        txt.removeSpan(mSpan);

        if (selStart != selEnd) {
            txt.setSpan(mSpan, selStart, selEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your res/color folder create a file called **text_color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#d48383"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#121212"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#d48383"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#d48383"/>

</selector>
```

Then inside your TextView set this as:

```
android:textColor="@color/text_color_selector"
```

Comment: I had already tried this but unfortunately this also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Create color folder in your res directory. Then add this xml file. Let's text_color_change.xml

**res/color/text_color_change.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#444"/>
    <item android:color="#ccc"/>

</selector>
```

Then in the TextView, add the textColor as the above file.

```
<TextView
    ....
    android:textColor="@color/text_color_change" />
```

Comment: This gives bg to selected text. I have already added this. I want to change `textColor` of highlighted text.

Comment: I had already tried this but unfortunately this also doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Add this property selector property, the selected item will keep it's color state until something else is selected.
in your

**selector.xml**  add this

```
        <!-- Activated -->      
<item 
    android:state_activated="true" 
    android:color="#ff0000" />

        <!-- Active -->      
<item 
    android:state_active="true" 
    android:color="#ff0000" />
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16791053/2826147) for more detail.

Comment: I had already tried this but unfortunately this also doesnt work.

Comment: You are right it changes color on selection. but the problem is it changes whole textView textColor where as I wanted to change only selected textColor.